# Bootstrap tab refresh on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tabs

On this project there is Bootstrap tab and Camera image slider. There is two tabs named Video news/ Picture news. And both have their sub tabs. And the subtabs use their own Camera slider. So the problem with this is when i click on subtabs the image sliders are breaking. What i need is to refresh the image slider or reload the slider so could they get their proper width.

So is there any proper way to do this?

```
Tab.active -> Sub tab -> Slider /on first it's ok/
           -> Sub tab -> Slider /Click on sub tab it breaks/
           -> Sub tab -> Slider
Tab        -> Sub tab -> Slider /all breaks/
           -> Sub tab -> Slider /Click on sub tab it breaks/
           -> Sub tab -> Slider
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to attach an event to Tabs and render the Camera slider when necessary.

Basically, you insert something like this into your code

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  // refresh the slider
})
```

Remember to change `a[data-toggle="tab"]` to match your tab links.

You have two events available:

- `shown.bs.tab` - This event fires on tab show, but before the new tab has been shown. Use `event.target` and `event.relatedTarget` to target the active tab and the previous active tab (if available) respectively.
- `shown.bs.tab` - This event fires on tab show after a tab has been shown. Use `event.target` and `event.relatedTarget` to target the active tab and the previous active tab (if available) respectively.

As you can see, by accessing active tab (`e.releatedTarget`) you can simply get the ID of the container where slider you need to refresh lives.

[Look at the "Events" section for more](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs)